# .NET Format a string with fixed spaces

Tags: .net, string

Does the .NET String.Format method allow placement of a string at a fixed position within a fixed length string.

```
"           String Goes Here"
"     String Goes Here      "
"String Goes Here           "
```

How is this done using .NET?

**Edit** - I have tried Format/PadLeft/PadRight to death.  They do not work.  I don't know why. I ended up writing my own function to do this.

**Edit** - I made a mistake and used a colon instead of a comma in the format specifier.  Should be "{0,20}".

Thanks for all of the excellent and correct answers.

Comment: I've never had a string formatting question that I couldn't answer by going to this page: http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: @jcollum: I'd love to up-vote your answer but no can do for comments

Comment: PadLeft works for me check that you are leaving the space in PadLeft(20,'HERE GOES A SPACE')

Comment: What do mean by "leaving the space in".  If you mean - am I "trimming" the string, then no.  It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 559):

This will give you exactly the strings that you asked for:

```
string s = "String goes here";
string lineAlignedRight  = String.Format("{0,27}", s);
string lineAlignedCenter = String.Format("{0,-27}",
    String.Format("{0," + ((27 + s.Length) / 2).ToString() +  "}", s));
string lineAlignedLeft   = String.Format("{0,-27}", s);
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer to the question, but it looks like the OP has left stackoverflow.

Comment: If you look for the green check vs. the highest up-votes, you don't know how to SO ;)

Comment: @DaveJellison Seems like someone needs to write a plugin to fix that, or SO should just make it a configurable user preference.

Comment: @WalterStabosz couldn't agree more.

Comment: Note that String.Format behavior is apparently different than Console.Write behavior with regard to left-alignment within a field.

Comment: why is this done with `,` instead of `:` like in all other formatting usecases?

Comment: @DaveJellison - but, sometimes a new and better answer arrives in the future that becomes the new selected answer, and obviously it will always start out with fewer votes.

Comment: very useful info

Comment: @Oliver Pfffft, no one should *EVER* *LEAVE* Stackoverflow!!

Comment: @LuckyLikey `,` use for "alignment" and `:` use for "format String"
 [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)

Answer (score 106):

As of Visual Studio 2015 you can also do this with [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx) (its a compiler trick, so it doesn't matter which version of the .net framework you target).

```
string value = "String goes here";
string txt1 = $"{value,20}";
string txt2 = $"{value,-20}";
```

Comment: its a c# 6 feature.

Comment: I've been using C#6 for years and didn't know that one! Upvoted :)

Comment: How to use for dynamic width, aka if instead of 20, the width is in a variable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 77):

The first and the last, at least, are possible using the following syntax:

```
String.Format("{0,20}", "String goes here");
String.Format("{0,-20}", "String goes here");
```

Answer (score 20):

You've been shown `PadLeft` and `PadRight`.  This will fill in the missing `PadCenter`.

```
public static class StringUtils
{
    public static string PadCenter(this string s, int width, char c)
    {
        if (s == null || width <= s.Length) return s;

        int padding = width - s.Length;
        return s.PadLeft(s.Length + padding / 2, c).PadRight(width, c);
    }
}
```

Note to self: don't forget to update own CV: "One day, I even fixed Joel Coehoorn's code!" ;-D -Serge

Comment: Joel, good snippet - I'm trying to use it and it doesn't quite center, the way it is.  Looks like the return line should be something like (I don't have enough rep to edit...):

return s.PadLeft((padding / 2) + s.Length, c).PadRight(width, c);

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
"String goes here".PadLeft(20,' ');
"String goes here".PadRight(20,' ');
```

for the center get the length of the string and do padleft and padright with the necessary characters

```
int len = "String goes here".Length;
int whites = len /2;
"String goes here".PadRight(len + whites,' ').PadLeft(len + whites,' ');
```

Comment: Seems like the String.Format() calls is superfluous.

Comment: Pad methods are good since the Format options require lengths to be constants (that is, `String.Format("{0,-length}", something)` won't compile.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the discussion, this method also works (VB):

```
Public Function StringCentering(ByVal s As String, ByVal desiredLength As Integer) As String
    If s.Length >= desiredLength Then Return s
    Dim firstpad As Integer = (s.Length + desiredLength) / 2
    Return s.PadLeft(firstpad).PadRight(desiredLength)
End Function
```

1. **StringCentering()** takes two input values and it returns a formatted
   string.
2. When length of **s** is greater than or equal to **deisredLength**, the function returns the original string.
3. When length of **s** is smaller than **desiredLength**, it will be padded both ends.
4. Due to character spacing is integer and there is no half-space, we can have an uneven split of space. In this implementation, the greater split goes to the leading end.
5. The function requires .NET Framework due to **PadLeft()** and **PadRight()**.
6. In the last line of the function, binding is from left to right, so **firstpad** is applied followed by the **desiredLength** pad.

Here is the C# version:

```
public string StringCentering(string s, int desiredLength)
{
    if (s.Length >= desiredLength) return s;
    int firstpad = (s.Length + desiredLength) / 2;
    return s.PadLeft(firstpad).PadRight(desiredLength);
}
```

To aid understanding, integer variable **firstpad** is used. **s.PadLeft(firstpad)** applies the (correct number of) leading white spaces. The right-most **PadRight(desiredLength)** has a lower binding finishes off by applying trailing white spaces.

Comment: Welcome to SO, chi.  This is yet another example of a GREAT first post and answer.  +1

Comment: Thanks Brian, the original question at the top of this post is an excellent starting point. I am inspired by all the posts and answers preceding mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VB.NET version I created, inspired by Joel Coehoorn's answer, Oliver's edit, and shaunmartin's comment:

```
    <Extension()>
Public Function PadCenter(ByVal [string] As String, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal c As Char) As String

    If [string] Is Nothing Then [string] = String.Empty
    If (width <= [string].Length) Then Return [string]

    Dim padding = width - [string].Length
    Return [string].PadLeft([string].Length + (padding \ 2), c).PadRight(width, c)

End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function PadCenter(ByVal [string] As String, ByVal width As Integer) As String

    If [string] Is Nothing Then [string] = String.Empty
    If (width <= [string].Length) Then Return [string]

    Dim padding = width - [string].Length
    Return [string].PadLeft([string].Length + (padding \ 2)).PadRight(width)

End Function
```

This is set up as a string extension, inside a Public Module (the way you do Extensions in VB.NET, a bit different than C#). My slight change is that it treats a null string as an empty string, and it pads an empty string with the width value (meets my particular needs).  Hopefully this will convert easily to C# for anyone who needs it.  If there's a better way to reference the answers, edits, and comments I mentioned above, which inspired my post, please let me know and I'll do it - I'm relatively new to posting, and I couldn't figure out to leave a comment (might not have enough rep yet).

Answer (score 0):

I posted a CodeProject article that may be what you want.

See: [A C# way for indirect width and style formatting.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403499/A-Csharp-way-for-indirect-width-and-style-formatti)

Basically it is a method, FormatEx, that acts like String.Format, except it allows a centered alignment modifier.

```
FormatEx("{0,c10}", value);
```

Means center the value of varArgs[0] in a 10 character wide field, lean right if an extra padding space is required.

```
FormatEx("{0,c-10}", value);
```

Means center the value of varArgs[0] in a 10 character wide field, lean left if an extra padding space is required.

Edit: Internally, it is a combination of Joel's PadCenter with some parsing to restructure the format and varArgs for a call to String.Format that does what you want.

-Jesse

Answer (score -1):

it seems like you want something like this, that will place you string at a fixed point in a string of constant length:

```
Dim totallength As Integer = 100
Dim leftbuffer as Integer = 5
Dim mystring As String = "string goes here"
Dim Formatted_String as String = mystring.PadLeft(leftbuffer + mystring.Length, "-") + String.Empty.PadRight(totallength - (mystring.Length + leftbuffer), "-")
```

note that this will have problems if mystring.length + leftbuffer exceeds totallength

Answer (score -9):

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a string With count chars Left or Right value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="val"></param>
/// <param name="count"></param>
/// <param name="space"></param>
/// <param name="right"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
 public static string Formating(object val, int count, char space = ' ', bool right = false)
{
    var value = val.ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < count - value.Length; i++) value = right ? value + space : space + value;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Don't use this code - it generates a lot of unnecessary string allocations. Use the builtin format specifiers and padding methods instead.

Comment: holy.. imagine using this inside a loop :)