# C# Formating Output for a File?

Tags: c#, string, file-io, int

I am creating a C# program that outputs text to a file. I want to align all information based of a set specification. For example, I want `line#` to have 20 chars of space, `message info` to have 25 chars of space. If the space is unused I want it to be empty spaces. I have searched everywhere and haven't been able to find anything to work.

I have included a basic example below. I used the periods for formatting in the post, I do not want to use them in my output.

```
Line #1.............Message Info #1      

Line #15............Message Info #15          

Line #534...........Message Info #534
```

Comment: As in you want somethere where `Message Info #1` and `Message Info #534` line up, regardless of how many numbers you print?

Comment: Consider looking at `String.format`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx .

Comment: Important: Font matters. You need a fixed font size or "Line Printer" font to obtain this look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here [net format a string with fixed spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces)

```
var line1 = String.Format("{0,20}", s);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with things other than strings? Example int?

Comment: @buzzzzjay I am not sure what you mean, but String.Format doesn't really care if it's an Int32 or String. Just to prove it, you can do myInt.ToString() and pass that as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is my go-to resource for string formatting in C#, which is essentially all you're doing:

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/