# Failing to use String.Format in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, string

I am a C++ developer and shifted to wpf last week. Well I have used sprintf in my c++ apps many time and now I have across the need of having something equivalent to that in C#. Here is what I had done is C++:

```
char t_str[4] = {};
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{ 
    sprintf(t_str, "%02X", buffer[i]);
m_apiResponse[i]->setText(String(t_str));
}
```

where `buffer[0] = 20;
                buffer[1] = 30;
                buffer[2] = 40;
                buffer[3] = 50;` and `m_apiResponse` is a textbox.

I had done this in my C# as follows:

```
Byte[] t_str = new Byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
         string bufstring = String.Format("{0:02}", buffer[i]);
         t_str = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bufstring);
}

Response1Box = Convert.ToString(t_str[0]);
Response2Box = Convert.ToString(t_str[1]);
Response3Box = Convert.ToString(t_str[2]);
Response4Box = Convert.ToString(t_str[3]);
```

where ResposeBox is a textbox which I have bind to:

```
// Description of Response1Box
    private string _Response1Box;
    public string Response1Box
    {
        get
        {
            return _Response1Box;
        }

        set
        {
            _Response1Box = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Response1Box");
        }
    }
```

`buffer[64]` is byte[].

Its not giving me the expected answer which my C++ method does. Is this the right way to do: `string bufstring = String.Format("{0:02}", buffer[i]);
             t_str = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bufstring);` Where am i wrong???

Please help :)

Comment: Well what is the expected answer / response that you are looking for..?

Comment: so, if i remember my C++, you want 0-padded 2-digit hex?

Comment: This may be a bit useful to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
string bufstring = String.Format("{0:D2}", buffer[i]);
```

or (for hex output)

```
string bufstring = String.Format("{0:X2}", buffer[i]);
```

or (with C/C++ style hex prefix)

```
string bufstring = String.Format("0x{0:X2}", buffer[i]);
```

See [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)  and [Standard Numeric Format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Of course, inside the C++ loop you call the `m_apiResponse[i]->setText`, you should do something similar in the C# loop to achieve the same result.

```
string[] response = new TextBox[] {Response1Box, Response2Box, Response3Box, Response4Box};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     response[i] = String.Format("{0:X2}", buffer[i]);
```

UPDATE:  It is not clear to me what ResponseBox is, but if you have 4 string properties named Response[X]Box inside an object instance called ResponseBox then you could set these properties outside the loop in this way

```
ResponseBox.Response1Box = response[0];
ResponseBox.Response2Box = response[1];
.......
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply STEVE :) response is basically a string. Since you have used TextBox[], its throwing errors :)

Comment: Throws error at Response1,2,3,4box since its a textbox property. Check my updated questioon :)

Answer (score 2):

I think there's something wrong with your byte array logic.

You have `byte[] t_str = new byte[4];` which is a byte array of 4.

However, you assign to `t_str` multiple times, overwriting the original 4 bytes.

You're probably looking for a declaration like:

```
byte[][] t_str = new byte[4][];
```

This will be an array of arrays.

And within your loop:

```
t_str[i] = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bufstring);
```

EDIT:

Or if I'm way off the mark, you could just do:

```
Response1Box = buffer[0].ToString("X2");
Response2Box = buffer[1].ToString("X2");
Response3Box = buffer[2].ToString("X2");
Response4Box = buffer[3].ToString("X2");
```

Assuming that `buffer` is a byte array, and you want to write out each individual bytes value

Answer (score 0):

Here's All String Formats that you might need in C# [Check Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format)
I expect you might need something as follow

```
String str = String.Format("Hello {0:0.00} {1:0.00}", 55, 20);
```