# padding / alignment in StringTemplate

Tags: stringtemplate-4

Q: What is the proper way for me add space-padding to the left or right of attributes (in order to achieve a fixed-width) in StringTemplate v4?

---

I am starting to use StringTemplate to generate some script text from Java code. 
There are situations in my output text where I would like to space-pad attributes so that they line up vertically. When doing so I would like to control whether the padding is on the left or right.

I observe that NumberRenderer uses Formatter.format() and allows "printf-style" format strings.

I want to do the same things with Strings ... e.g. "%-30s"

However, I am puzzled to see that StringRenderer does not use the same Formatter.format() code.

I also do not see any other type of String-related AttributeRenderer in the StringTemplate4 JavaDoc.

This leads me to wonder if perhaps there is another mechanism that I should be using to accomplish this.

Q: What is the proper way for me add space-padding to the left or right of attributes (in order to achieve a fixed-width) in StringTemplate v4?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

StringTemplate 4 provides a `StringRenderer` class that you can register with your group.

```
group.registerRenderer(String.class, new StringRenderer());
```

This renderer supports several predefined format strings like `upper` and `lower`, but you can also pass it any other format string like `%-30s` which it will pass on to a call to `String.format()`.

Comment: For .NET, use the string.Format width specifier, e.g. `<name; format="{0,-20}">`  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces