# How do I write data column b y column to a csv file

Tags: c#

I have a big problem with writing some data to a csv file. I have  a lot of measurement values. Every value is described by name, unit, value. So i want to build for every value a column with these three properties.
I want to store it into the csv file like this:

```
Width    Cell Wall Thickness   Coarseness   Curl-Index    etc.
mm           mm                    mg/m         %         etc.
16,2         3,2                  0,000       11,7        etc.
```

Till now i was coding a header for the names, another for the units and the values (that were previously stored into a string array) i just wrote in one line. 
Till now my csv file looks like this:(

```
Width;Cell Wall Thickness;Coarseness;Curl-Index;etc.
mm;mm;mg/m;%;etc.
16,2;3,2;0,000;11,7;etc.
```

if it were not many values i wouldn't care about this but there are a lot so when i open the csv file there's the problem that the headers dont fit to the values and units. It's not organized, i cannot match the values to the headers. 
I would like everything to be organized in columns. Any help would be strongly appreciated!
That's the code that i have till now:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test2.csv");
    int RowCount = 3;
    int ColumnCount = 4;
string[][] Transfer_2D = new string[RowCount][];
Transfer_2D[0] = new string[3]{"Width", "CWT", "Coarseness", "Curl-Index"};//name of the values
Transfer_2D[1] = new string[3] {"mm", "mm", "mg/m", "%"};   //units
Transfer_2D[2] = new string[3] { TransferData[0], TransferData[1], TransferData[2],    TransferData[3] };
for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            sw.Write(Transfer_2D[i][j]);//write one row separated by columns
            if (j < ColumnCount)
            {
                sw.Write(";");//use ; as separator between columns
            }
        }
        if (i < RowCount)
        {
            sw.Write("\n");//use \n to separate between rows
        }
    }

    sw.Close();

 }
```

Comment: May you edit the "expected" result with `;` and `,`, it would be better if you can provide few sample data

Comment: CSV file is not meant to be "nice". It is meant to be used by a machine, but also understood and edited by a human. Ease of reading is not an issue with csv files. If you want humans to read the file with ease you would have to choose some other format. HTML for instance, using a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the string to a fixed length.
example look here: ([.NET Format a string with fixed spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces))

```
int iWantedStringLength = 20;

string sFormatInstruction = "{0,-" + iWantedStringLength.ToString() + "}";

for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            sw.Write(String.Format(sFormatInstruction, Transfer_2D[i][j]));//write one row separated by columns
            if (j < ColumnCount)
            {
                sw.Write(";");//use ; as separator between columns
            }
        }
        if (i < RowCount)
        {
            sw.Write("\n");//use \n to separate between rows
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For CSV work I use http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/, this is a very nice helper class but it would require you to change your working a little bit.

I would advice you create a class to store each entry in and then create a "Mapper" to map it to csv fields. Then you can just pass a collection of objects and your mapping class to the helper and it produces a structured CSV.

There are alot of examples on that page so it should be straight forward for you to work through.