# Get file size and Name into two different column using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssis, c#-3.0, ssis-2012

I want to get all the files name and their size and save it into an Excel using C#.
I have done this but the problem is I want two different column: one for filename and one for Filesize, but my output is saved in one column.

The code I'm using:

```
public void Main()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\MyFile\\output.csv"))
    {
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        Act();
    }
}

static void Act()
{
    Console.Write("FileName,".PadRight(20));
    Console.WriteLine("Size");
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\MyFile");
    // Get a reference to each file in that directory.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();
    // Display the names and sizes of the files.
    //Console.WriteLine("The directory {0} contains the following files:", di.Name);
    foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} ", f.Name.PadRight(20), f.Length.ToString());
}
```

How can I split this into two columns?

Comment: What is your definition of the concept 'Columns'?

Comment: You seem to have correctly put "," in between the two items as well as having `csv` file. What is the problem you got?

Comment: It means I want Filename in Column A and Filesize in Column B. But in my code both filename and size is shown in column A

Comment: you have a CSV file and it shows name and length being written to two fields, perhaps its how you're importing it to excel?

Comment: I am trying this as I am not able to do it in excel

Comment: Why are you using `Console` to write to the csv instead of the `FileSystemObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Try seperating the fields with a tab.

```
foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t {1} ", f.Name.PadRight(20), f.Length.ToString());
```

Good luck my friend.

Comment: Have you tried using new line?  `Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} {2} ", f.Name.PadRight(20), "\n" ,f.Length.ToString());`

Comment: yes for new line it goes to a new line but i want the next column

Comment: Haha now i think i've found it. `Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2} ", f.Name.PadRight(20), ";" ,f.Length.ToString());`

Comment: No its not working
It gives the result under A column
a.txt       ;19039 
b.txt        ;734

Comment: weird. Anyway, i've looked it up and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404677/how-do-i-write-data-column-b-y-column-to-a-csv-file). They also suggest using **;**.