# String formatting with spaces

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I need to do some hand made formatting in c# with only spaces. Here's what I display now:

```
Conc2_CO   ( Y? = 170.2; Y? = 2; delta = -15)
atns_UreaMassFlowDemand   ( Y? = 0; Y? = 0; delta = 0)
```

And this is what I'd like to have:

```
Conc2_CO                 ( Y? = 170.2; Y? = 2;     delta  = -15)
atns_UreaMassFlowDemand  ( Y? = 0;     Y? = 0;     delta  = 0)
```

I tried playing with string length using `new string(' ', x)` but this is a big pain and seems to work randomly since all the characters don't have the same length (i.e: `l` is shorter than `w`)... Is there some better option?

### Edit:

The resulting string is construct with the concatenation of the name (left) and the informations I add (right) in a library so I can't use string.format() since I can only play with the right part.

I need to display this information on the ZedGraph Legend using WinForms (but I doubt this will change anything).

### Edit 2

Using paddings, this is what I've got:

[image]

Which is **not** what I want.

Comment: Check out string.format() http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

Comment: @RoyDictus I forgot to mention that the string is weirdly constructed, I'll edit my question

Comment: There's a question on here that shows how to pad spaces in a string. Maybe it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces

Comment: Since you say "the characters don't have the same length" I assume you are *not* talking about console or fixed-length output in general here. That means you have to take the font into account that is being used to render the output. Search for "MeasureString" or "MeasureText" on SO.

Comment: Well, you can measure your strings precisely using `Graphics.MeasureString` thus problem "all the characters don't have the same length" will gone away.

Comment: how many spaces are you wanting use..? are you familiar with new string method you can do something like this `var custSpaces = new string(' ', 15)` for example

Comment: If you manually add spaces, can you get that text aligned? Because if the font is not console-like, it's very likely that you can't achieve that with spaces, you would need a fraction of a space for an exact alignment. An invisible table may be a better option in your case. PS: Do you want to remove the "delta"s??

Comment: @Andrew I have to deal with string only solution and if the error is < to one space, I'll consider the job done.

Comment: @Thomas why string.format() doesn't work for you

Comment: @user2397162 because all the string doesn't correspond to the same number of spaces

Comment: @Thomas on what depends the number of spaces ?

Comment: @user2397162 the string `llll` isn't the same width than `wwww` in graphics fonts

Comment: @Thomas are you working with winforms ?!!

Comment: @user2397162 with zedgraph. Did you read the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your font in order to use a [monospace](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) font.

This way you will be able to use the `String.Format` and work with paddings.

Comment: I provided a link to help users to do the job, but thanks MM!

Answer (score 0):

I was delete may previous answer.
Try this:

```
 string s = String.Format("{0,-12}({1,8})", "Example", 223);
```

{0,-12} -0 - value index, -12 align to left 12 chars
{1,8} - 1 - value index, 8 align to right 8 chars

More:http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx see: The format item

Comment: Could you add Code with generate your result? I think it sth wrong because pading should gave place for value. in your case it looks like it give only space between words.