# Formatting a multiline string to be printed on a receipt

Tags: c#, string, printing

I am trying to print a multiline string on a paper from my windows forms application and it does print fine but the formatting is applying only to the first line which is being printed slightly to the right and other lines are being aligned to left for which I would like all the lines to be printed just like the first line

Example

```
    ID : value
Head : value
Hand : value
```

as you can see from the above ID is printer slightly to the right but head and hand lines are not aligned with the first line

```
    sb.Append(strTempMessage + NEW_LINE);
                    strTempMessage = AlignNumeric("        ", PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN);
                    strTempMessage += AlignMessage(strPickSlipNote,0);
                    sb.Append(strTempMessage + NEW_LINE);

public string AlignMessage(string strMessage, int intBeginningBlankSpace)
        {
            strMessage = strMessage.Trim();
            return AlignNumeric(strMessage, intBeginningBlankSpace);
        }

        public string AlignNumeric(string strMessage, int intBeginningBlankSpace)
        {
            intBeginningBlankSpace += strMessage.Length;
            if (intBeginningBlankSpace > 0)
                return strMessage.PadLeft(intBeginningBlankSpace, ' ');
            else
                return strMessage;
        }
```

**what changes should I make to get all the lines aligned?**

Comment: Take a look at this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped solve

```
 public string FormatPickSlipNoteLines(string input)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return "";
            else if (input.Length < PAGE_COLUMN_SIZE)
                return ALIGN_PAGE_CENTER + input + ALIGN_PAGE_LEFT;
            else
            {
                string[] str = input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);               
                StringBuilder sbFormatter = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                {
                    sbFormatter.Append("        " + str[i] + NEW_LINE);                 
                }
                return sbFormatter.Append(NEW_LINE + ALIGN_PAGE_LEFT).ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if its the most efficient way doing this but you can add tab after appending new line e.g. `sb.Append(strTempMessage + NEW_LINE + "\t");`