# C# how to set a fix field width using string interpolation?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and in this case, I want to align text columns in a text block. 
So basically I am trying to print a receipt and on the receipt, it should look like this.

For example:

```
1 Dinner Set          $15.00
1 Hamburger Combo     $10.00
```

Basically, I want to align my text column for the receipt. Since the food item name length varies from the different food item. For instance "Dinner Set" and "Hamburger Combo" have different lengths. Therefore, whenever I use the code below it would come up like this

```
1 Diner Set          $15.00
1 Hamburger Combo       $10.00
```

Here is the code:

```
    foreach (OrderItem ot in orderItemList)
    {
      x += $"\n{ot.Quantity} {ot.Item.Name}\t\t 
      ${ot.GetItemTotalAmnt().ToString("0.00")}\n";
    }
```

Since I don't hardcode each line is there a way to set a fixed width on {ot.Item.Name}?

Comment: Here is another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces

Comment: @S.Akbari However the problem is i don't hardcode each line so is there a way to set a fixed width on the ot.Item.Name field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you're using a fixed-width font, use something like this:

```
string.Format("{0,-20}", ot.Item.Name)
```

The value after the comma says to use that many character spaces in the resulting string. If you use the following (notice I removed the minus sign):

```
string.Format("{0,20}", ot.Item.Name)
```

Then the text will be right-aligned within those spaces.

Comment: so if we say that we set 20 character spaces are the "Diner Set" character included within that 20 characters spaces?

Comment: @JmSanDiego: Yes, exactly. Try it.

Comment: alright ill give it a shot!

Comment: unfortunately, the same thing happens I put {ot.Item.Name, -20} but the right column are still aren't aligned

Comment: @JmSanDiego: Please read my answer again. No one said to write what you wrote.

Comment: my bad, i got mixed up with the other answers! il

Comment: Please see my update to my answer.

Comment: Hi sir is there an expression for $" " method?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not sure how to specify formatting characters within a `$` string. But try adding it to the string passed to `ToString()` in your original code. But since you're calling `ToString()` anyway, I think `String.Format()` is better.

Comment: thank you for your time sir i appreciate it

Comment: A small correction: string.Format("{0,20}", ot.Item.Name) will align to the right. string.Format("{0,-20}", ot.Item.Name) align to the left. Monospace font is mandatory to get text aligned.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the field width and format specifiers the same way with string interpolation as you can with `String.Format()`.

```
x += $"\n{ot.Quantity} {ot.Item.Name,-20} ${ot.GetItemTotalAmnt():C}\n";
```

And if you don't want to hardcode 20, just use the maximum `Item.Name` as the field width.

```
var maxLength = orderItemList.Max(ot => ot.Item.Name.Length)
```

Comment: i did the same thing unfortunately same output happens

Comment: And you removed the `\t\t`? I had to ask.

Comment: yep i did as well!

Comment: The output is exactly the same as what you show in your post?

Comment: unfortunately yes