# Output floating point width and precision C#?

Tags: c#, format, width, precision

I'm moving some C++ code to C# and need formatted tabular information that has floating point numbers.  Is there a way to duplicate `printf("%f8.2",fNumber);` where both width and precision are honored in a single call?

```
float f1 = 12345.67; 
float f2 =    45.67; 
Console.Output("{0:F2}",f1.PadLeft(8)); // works, but isn't a single call
Console.Output("{0:F2}",f2.PadLeft(8));

// desired output
12345.67
   45.67
```

Comment: See [.NET Format a string with fixed spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will display your numbers to width of 8 and width of two decimal places:

```
Debug.WriteLine("{0,8:F2}", f1);
```

You can find relevant documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros).