# Question: Is There A Way To Format White-space Like This In C#?

Tags: c#, formatting, whitespace

**Is There A Way To Format White-space Like This In C#?**

I would like to know if you could parse string arrays into a method and get it to return you a formatted string with white-spaces, there is a specific way i need this done so **here's an example:**

```
string[][] StringArray = new string[][] {
    new string[] {"Name:", "John Jones."}
    new string[] {"Date of birth:", "07/11/1989."}
    new string[] {"Age:", "29 Years old."}
};

FormatWhiteSpace(StringArray, Padding: 5);
```

**Output would be:**

```
Name:              John Jones.
Date of birth:     07/11/1989.
Age:               29 Years old.
```

As you see above in the output everything is lined up and with 5 spaces for padding as defined when we called the method. This is exactly what we want. Also we have a 2 dimensional array because that allows us to parse in more than 1 line at once. **Here's another example, this time with more than two columns:**

```
string[][] StringArray = new string[][] {
    new string[] {"Name:", "John", "Jones."}
    new string[] {"Date of birth:", "Monday,", "07/11/1989."}
    new string[] {"Age:", "29", "Years old."}
};

FormatWhiteSpace(StringArray, Padding: 2);
```

**Second Output would be:**

```
Name:           John     Jones.
Date of birth:  Monday,  07/11/1989.
Age:            29       Years old.
```

> That's all i would like to know if you know of anything that can help
>   me please let me know. Thanks for your help, you guys really made my
>   day.

Comment: If you are asking if there is an inbuilt way to do this, then the answer is no, but you can obviously write code that behaves the way you require; `string.PadRight` looks like a good starting point.

Comment: I'm asking if anyone knows how. I would like an in-built way but if there isn't then I'm asking if someone could create code or direct me towards creating it. And thanks for the advice.

Comment: This isnt a place where people write code for you. This is a place where you ask about specific problems in your code that you don't know how to solve.

Comment: Make two passes through the main (rows) array.  On the first pass, Create a second collection that consists of the max widths of each column.  On the second pass, output each string padded using the information about the max width of the column it's in (plus a little extra).

Comment: Have you looked at String.Format eg: `String.Format("{0,27}", s);`

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I didn't realize, but I am working on a project and i need this for the project and from your comment you say that this is a place for solving problems in code, well this is kind of what I'm doing because i just don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: I will look at String.Format thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Format a string with fixed spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces)

Comment: This would be a good case for using `string.PadRight` and `string.Format`

Comment: You need to decide whether you use fixed or variable fonts. and what 'output' is supposed to mean: output to a text file and which type or a pixel canvas..??

Comment: @RanOutOfQuestions: Did you like either (or both) of the answers you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally love using Linq, also this works with any number of columns and will calculate the distance needed for each column.

```cs
void Main()
{
    string[][] StringArray = new string[][] {
    new [] {"Name:", "John", "Jones."},
    new [] {"Date of birth:", "Monday,", "07/11/1989."},
    new [] {"Age:", "29", "Years old."}};

    var lines = FormatWhiteSpace(StringArray, Padding: 2);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> FormatWhiteSpace(string[][] StringArray, int Padding)
{
    var maxLengthDict = StringArray
        .Select(sa => sa.Select((s, i) => new { Column = i, MaxLength = s.Length }))        
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Column)
        .Select(x => new {Column = x.Key, MaxLength = x.Max(y => y.MaxLength)})
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Column, x => x.MaxLength);

    return StringArray
        .Select(sa => string.Concat(sa.Select((s, i) => s.PadRight(maxLengthDict[i] + Padding))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I added an extra row to your data to make it not square and make debugging more obvious):

```
public static class PaddedColumns
{
    private static string[][] _stringArray = new string[][] {
        new [] {"Name:", "John", "Jones."},
        new [] {"Date of birth:", "Monday,", "07/11/1989."},
        new [] {"Age:", "29", "Years old."},
        new [] {"Eye Color:", "blue", ""},
    };

    public static void PadIt()
    {
        OutputPadded(_stringArray);
    }

    public static void OutputPadded(string[][] strings)
    {
        var columnMaxes = new int[strings[0].Length];

        foreach (var row in strings)
        {
            for (var colNo = 0; colNo < row.Length; ++colNo)
            {
                if (row[colNo].Length > columnMaxes[colNo])
                {
                    columnMaxes[colNo] = row[colNo].Length;
                }
            }
        }

        const int extraPadding = 2;

        //got the maxes, now go through and use them to pad things
        foreach (var row in strings)
        {
            for (var colNo = 0; colNo < row.Length; ++colNo)
            {
                Console.Write(row[colNo].PadRight(columnMaxes[colNo] + extraPadding));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

    }

}
```

The result looks like:

```
Name:           John     Jones.
Date of birth:  Monday,  07/11/1989.
Age:            29       Years old.
Eye Color:      blue
```

Comment: One thing to note is that @carloBos's and my solution use the same algorithm, just with two radically different implementations. If you aren't going to use LINQ, and you want to return a collection of fully formed lines (as does @CarloBos), consider using a StringBuilder rather than using straight-up string concatenation.  I've yet to find a good way to concatenate things using StringBuilders and LINQ.