# c# making all lines same length adding spaces from text file

Tags: c#, line

I have text file so it looks like this.

```
Some old wounds never truly heal, and bleed again at the slightest word.
Fear cuts deeper than swords.
Winter is coming.
If I look back I am lost.
Nothing burns like the cold.
```

and I need to make that lines to be same length as longest one adding spaces

```
static void Reading(string fd, out int nr)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fd, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
    int length = 0;
    nr = 0;
    int nreil = 0;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Length > length)
        {
            length = line.Length;
            nr = nreil;
        }
        nreil++;
    }
}
```

edit: simply padding the sentences with whitespaces between words

Comment: Do you mean justfying the text or simply padding the sentences with whitespaces?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155195/how-to-justify-text-in-a-label) can help.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401292/question-is-there-a-way-to-format-white-space-like-this-in-c/53402090#53402090, and instead of adding all the spaces to the end, calculate the number of word breaks in each line (during the first pass), divide the number of spaces you need by the number of word breaks, and distribute the spaces into the breaks.

Comment: Get a look into monospaced fonts. Using a monospaced font to display it, you could pad left or right as desired.

Comment: @bradbury9, InBetween,  _"same length ... adding spaces"_ - there is nothing in the question that suggests rendering to pixels or outlining anything.

Comment: @bommelding I'm not talking about outlining or pixels. You can either pad right or you can justify the text inserting addiontal spaces in between words to get an exacact right alignment.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Since OP specified they wanted spacing between words, I have removed my end of line padding example, leaving only the justify code.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fd, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
int maxLength = lines.Max(l => l.Length);
lines = lines.Select(l => l.Justify(maxLength)).ToArray();

public static string Justify(this string input, int length)
{
    string[] words = input.Split(' ');
    if (words.Length == 1)
    {
        return input.PadRight(length);
    }
    string output = string.Join(" ", words);
    while (output.Length < length)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < words.Length - 1; w++)
        {
            words[w] += " ";
            output = string.Join(" ", words);
            if (output.Length == length)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Take a chill pill. I'm looking for words because it wasn't clear if the OP was asking for end of line padding, or justification of the line.

Comment: Also, did you try running it before saying it won't work?

Comment: Also, I don't need to handle the carriage return... File.ReadAllLines does that for me

Comment: If you're still confused, feel free to point out WHY you think it wont work

Comment: What happens if you have three spaces between words?  lines = File.ReadAllLines(fd, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)) returns a string not an array.

Comment: Then they get counted as separate words for justification purposes. ReadAllLines returns an array ReadAllText returns a string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Dealing with multi spaced text would require a whole bunch of choices, like do I maintain original spacing ratios, do I fill low count spacing first, do I reduce spaces to one then justify?

Comment: @jdweng Anything else?

Comment: If you are done nitpicking, you can delete your first comment. I won't think any less of you for it. Maybe next time you'll take 5 minutes to understand something before calling it the worst you've ever seen?

Comment: Why split the lines when it is absolutely unnecessary and just wastes a lot of time.  And what does encoding do?  The only thing you need to do is add spaces at end of line. There is just a lot of useless garbage in this code.

Comment: Please re-read the original question. The OP made an edit that says he is specifically looking for "simply padding the sentences with whitespaces between words"

Comment: Also, the encoding is from the original question... which you completely ignored in your answer

Comment: and seriously, if all we are doing is adding spaces to the end of the line, then your answer is about 20 lines too long

Comment: Why change existing white spaces between words?  I could understand if the OP wanted to change tabs to spaces, but you code doesn't not do anything with tabs.

Comment: ...because that's specifically what the OP is asking for? From the OP: "simply padding the sentences with whitespaces between words"

Comment: If the OP ask you to stand on your head would you do it?  Why complicate the code when it is not necessary?

Comment: I honestly can't tell if you're trolling at this point. This is like if someone asked me for directions to the nearest airport, and you immediately interrupted me to give directions to the nearest bus stop, then argued that buses are better

Comment: @Broom But didn't you know, cars are the preferred method of travel?

Comment: My point is you won't stand on your head because it is not needed in the code.  So why are you splitting and joining when it has nothing to do with adding padding at end of line.

Comment: And my point is padding at the end of the line has nothing to do with the OP's question