# Ways to improve string memory allocation

Tags: c#, .net, string, optimization, stringbuilder

This question is more theoretical than practical, but still.

I've been looking for a chance to improve the following code from the string memory allocation standpoint:

```
/* Output for n = 3:
*
*  '  #'
*  ' ##'
*  '###'
*
*/
public static string[] staircase(int n) {
    string[] result = new string[n];

    for(var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) {
        var spaces = string.Empty.PadLeft(n - i - 1, ' ');
        var sharpes = string.Empty.PadRight(i + 1, '#');

        result[i] = spaces + sharpes;
    }

    return result;
}
```

[PadHelper](https://github.com/fixdpt/shared-source-cli-2.0/blob/d63349c09c2e93e4bfc4c8b147ff0805f36cec68/clr/src/vm/comstring.cpp#L1305-L1325) is the method, that is eventually called under the hood twice per iteration.

So, correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like memory is allocated at least 3 times per iteration.

Any code improvements will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be slightly barking up the wrong tree in that the biggest win for a method like this would be to eliminate the `string[]` altogether, and all that's used to generate it. If used directly as output, the net result is printing nine characters and three newlines (well, X and Y depending on `n`) and that can be done without any explicit allocations at all. (Or, slightly more realistically, since printing single characters is rather inefficient, with just one string buffer for all lines.)

Comment: Perhaps you could allocate a single string with `n - 1` spaces _and_ `n` sharpes outside the loop, then return a substring of that for each `i`, starting at offset `i`.

Comment: yes strings in .NET are immutable. So any string manipulation results into new allocation. _StringBuilder_ class could maybe help here

Comment: You should not be concerned with premature optimization. If the code works fast enough then no optimization is needed.

Comment: Well, agree with all of your points, but since it's a theoretical task, I'm just investigating other options to accomplish that :)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/644017

Comment: StringBuilder is always an answer when it comes to string allocations; I'm sure you know that so apparently you want something else. Well, since your strings are all the same length, you can declare a single `char[]` array, populate it every time (only requires changing two adjacent elements on each iteration) and then use the [`string(char[])` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char___).

Comment: @GSerg wow, it seems like your solution even takes less operations because of just two updates per iteration and requires a constant amount of memory for holding the array. It might be the best answer.

Comment: If you make the function returns `IEnumerable<string>` with `yield return` then you wouldn't even need the string array.

Comment: The concept of Stack Overflow is that a question must be "acceptable", meaning there has to be an answer that OP would eventually accept. If you find such answer beyond those already written then you should write it yourself, and accept it. Otherwise the question is asking for opinions, and those questions are not good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Dialecticus, agree, perfectly makes sense. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is always an answer when it comes to string allocations; I'm sure you know that so apparently you want something else. Well, since your strings are all the same length, you can declare a single `char[]` array, populate it every time (only requires changing one array element on each iteration) and then use the [`string(char[])` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char___):

```cs
public static string[] staircase(int n)
{
    char[] buf = new char[n];
    string[] result = new string[n];

    for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = ' ';
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        buf[n - i - 1] = '#';
        result[i] = new string(buf);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
result[i] = new string('#',i).PadLeft(n)
```

?

Note that this *still* allocates two strings internally, but I honestly don't see that as a problem. The garbage collector will take care of it for you.

Comment: It seems like it depends on the string's constructor implementation, but looks reasonable. Thank you for this one.

Comment: @FSou1 "It seems like it depends on the string's constructor implementation" Yes - is that a bad thing? The constructor implementation is documented so there should be no risk of it changing.

Answer (score 2):

You can save on both allocations and speed by starting with a string that contains all the Spaces and all the Sharpes you're ever going to need, and then taking substrings from that, as follows:

```
public string[] Staircase2()
{
    string allChars = new string(' ', n - 1) + new string('#', n); // n-1 spaces + n sharpes

    string[] result = new string[n];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        result[i] = allChars.Substring(i, n);

    return result;
}
```

I used [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) to compare `Staircase1` (your original approach) with `Staircase2` (my approach above) from `n=2` upto `n=8`, see the results below.

It shows that `Staircase2` is always faster (see the `Mean` column), and it allocates fewer bytes starting from `n=3`.

```
|     Method | n |        Mean |      Error |     StdDev | Allocated |
|----------- |-- |------------:|-----------:|-----------:|----------:|

| Staircase1 | 2 |   229.36 ns |  4.3320 ns |  4.0522 ns |      92 B |
| Staircase2 | 2 |    92.00 ns |  0.7200 ns |  0.6735 ns |     116 B |

| Staircase1 | 3 |   375.06 ns |  3.3043 ns |  3.0908 ns |     156 B |
| Staircase2 | 3 |   114.12 ns |  2.8933 ns |  3.2159 ns |     148 B |

| Staircase1 | 4 |   507.32 ns |  3.8995 ns |  3.2562 ns |     236 B |
| Staircase2 | 4 |   142.78 ns |  1.4575 ns |  1.3634 ns |     196 B |

| Staircase1 | 5 |   650.03 ns | 15.1515 ns | 25.7284 ns |     312 B |
| Staircase2 | 5 |   169.25 ns |  1.9076 ns |  1.6911 ns |     232 B |

| Staircase1 | 6 |   785.75 ns | 16.9353 ns | 15.8413 ns |     412 B |
| Staircase2 | 6 |   195.91 ns |  2.9852 ns |  2.4928 ns |     292 B |

| Staircase1 | 7 |   919.15 ns | 11.4145 ns | 10.6771 ns |     500 B |
| Staircase2 | 7 |   237.55 ns |  4.6380 ns |  4.9627 ns |     332 B |

| Staircase1 | 8 | 1,075.66 ns | 26.7013 ns | 40.7756 ns |     620 B |
| Staircase2 | 8 |   255.50 ns |  2.6894 ns |  2.3841 ns |     404 B |
```

This doesn't mean that Staircase2 is the absolute best possible, but certainly there is a way that is better than the original.

Comment: Your method seem to be missing the `int n` argument.

Comment: Because of how BenchmarkDotNet works, it is easiest to declare the variable `n` outside of the methods and letting BM.Net set its value for all methods under test, in this case with values from 2 to 8. This applies for both my methods `Staircase1` and `Staircase2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can project your desired results using the Linq `Select` method. For example, something like this:

```
public static string[] staircase(int n) {
    return Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(i => new string('#', i).PadLeft(n)).ToArray();
}
```

Alternate approach using an `int` array:

```
public static string[] staircase(int n) {
    return (new int[n]).Select((x,i) => new string('#', i+1).PadLeft(n)).ToArray();
}
```

HTH

Comment: That would be exactly the [D Stanley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220891/11683), just for the entire array.

Comment: Truth be told, one line solutions are always looking elegent, so I love it :)

Comment: @GSerg The idea is to demonstrate the projection using Linq `Select`

Comment: @FSou1 the idea is to produce an array of integers that you can then project to padded strings. The string padding is not an issue IMO and you would benefit more by minimizing the instantiation and enumeration of objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also try putting things on the stack where it makes sense.

public void StaircaseSpan()
    {
        Span<char> characters = stackalloc char[n];
        characters.Fill(' ');
        var rows = new string[n];

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            characters[i] = '#';
            rows[i] = characters.ToString();
        }
    }
```

n=3

```
|          Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Gen0 | Allocated |
|---------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|----------:|
|   StaircaseSpan | 33.26 ns | 0.161 ns | 0.151 ns | 0.0688 |     144 B |
| StaircaseString | 67.98 ns | 0.494 ns | 0.438 ns | 0.1223 |     256 B |
```

n=8

```
|          Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Gen0 | Allocated |
|---------------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|----------:|
|   StaircaseSpan |  85.79 ns | 0.940 ns | 0.880 ns | 0.1950 |     408 B |
| StaircaseString | 209.93 ns | 0.499 ns | 0.417 ns | 0.4170 |     872 B |
```

Comment: Using `$"{... something ...}{... something ...}"` with C#10's new interpolated string handling, should also reduce allocations.