# How do I get a two dimensional array to align in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am attempting to print a two dimensional array in C#. I have succeeded in printing the columns and rows properly, but I cannot figure out how to get them to align properly so it is a square. Is there any way to format it so it appears as a proper square? (as in the shape)

My code is

```
           int[,] array1 = new int[6, 6]
           {
               {10, 20, 10, 20, 21, 99 },
               {2, 27, 5, 45, 20, 13 },
               {17, 20, 20, 33, 33, 20 },
               {21, 35, 15, 54, 20, 37 },
               {31, 101, 25, 55, 26, 66 },
               {45, 20, 44, 12, 55, 98 }
           };`

           int Length = array1.GetLength(0);
           int Height = array1.GetLength(1);

           for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
               {
                   Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", array1[i, j]));
               }
               Console.Write("\n" + "\n");
           }
```

Comment: Do you just want to [left-pad the single-digit numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/644171/424129) with a space?

Comment: `Console.Write(string.Format("{0,3} ", array1[i, j]));` where `3` means pad to up to length `3` from the left

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Just a clarification on @DmitryBychenko example.  If you use `3`, it will pad on the _left_.  If you need it to pad on the _right_ use `-3`:  `Console.Write(string.Format("{0,-3}", array1[i, j]));` or using an interpolated string : `Console.Write($"{array1[i, j],-3}");`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a TAB character to your output:

```cs
Console.Write(array1[i, j].ToString() + '\t');
```

Or Pad the numbers:

```cs
Console.Write(string.Format("{0,3} ", array1[i, j]));
```

Where 3 is the max amount of digits for your values.