# While loop iteration displays strange tabulation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
    using (SqlDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //iterate loop results 
                while (myDataReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"-> Make : {myDataReader["MakeId"]},\t " +
                        $"PetNAme : {myDataReader["PetName"]},\t" +
                        $" Color : {myDataReader["Color"]}.");

                }
            }
```

The output
++++++++ Fun with Data Readers AutoLot++++++++++++

```
-> Make : 1,     PetNAme : Zippy,        Color : Black.
-> Make : 2,     PetNAme : Rusty,        Color : Rust.
-> Make : 3,     PetNAme : Mel,  Color : Black.// <- this one |||||||||||
-> Make : 4,     PetNAme : Clunker,      Color : Yellow.
-> Make : 5,     PetNAme : Bimmer,       Color : Black.
-> Make : 5,     PetNAme : Hank,         Color : Green.
-> Make : 5,     PetNAme : Pinky,        Color : Pink.
-> Make : 6,     PetNAme : Pete,         Color : Black.
-> Make : 4,     PetNAme : Brownie,      Color : Brown.
```

While loop displays strange tabulation with one element , any ideas why did this happen ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8lHj.png)

Comment: Because a name needs to be at least 4 chars to make it to the next tab stop.. Try calling "Mel" "Melanie"

Comment: That string is short enough that the next tab stop is closer than the rest. Best to format using a fixed width for each column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces/644171

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem mark it as an acceptable answer. If it helps you give it an upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: changing the value to : Melanie does the trick @Caius Jard

Comment: Is this statement about tab only in databases ? Because regular loop iteration with tab works just fine like it should .... 
string[] array = { "a", "as", "asd", "asdf" };
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{array[i]}\t");

            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query for the longest pet name, use the length in a PadRight as shown below.  Change the server and table name to match your database.

```
public static void Demo()
{
    using var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ForumExample;Integrated Security=True");
    var sql = "SELECT LEN(PetName) +2 AS length FROM Pet WHERE LEN(PetName) = " + 
              "(SELECT MAX(LEN(PetName)) FROM Pet)";

    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

    cn.Open();

    var nameLength = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MakeId, PetName, Color FROM dbo.Pet;";

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    
    Debug.WriteLine("++++++++ Fun with Data Readers AutoLot++++++++++++");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"-> Make : {reader.GetInt32(0),-4}PetName : {reader.GetString(1).PadRight(nameLength)}Color : {reader.GetString(2)}");
    }

}
```

Results

```
++++++++ Fun with Data Readers AutoLot++++++++++++
-> Make : 1   PetName : Zippy    Color : Black
-> Make : 2   PetName : Rusty    Color : Rust
-> Make : 3   PetName : Mel      Color : Black
-> Make : 4   PetName : Clunker  Color : Yellow
-> Make : 5   PetName : Bimmer   Color : Black
-> Make : 6   PetName : Hank     Color : Green
-> Make : 7   PetName : Pinky    Color : Pink
-> Make : 8   PetName : Pete     Color : Black
-> Make : 9   PetName : Browie   Color : Brown
```

Comment: Note that if this is being done for "make a fixed width report" purposes, I think i would just pick a width and use it/truncate anything over the limit. If the report is being consumed by a remote machine, then varying the width may cause problems.. (Not a criticism of the answer, more a caution to the OP/future visitors - if youre making a fixed width file, fix the widths. If youre making a delimited file, care not its presentation in the console)

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is a Tab character.  One Tab character will advance the output to whatever the next tab stop is.  Which is exactly what's happening on every line of output.

For example, open a word processor and type:

```
this is some long text<tab><return>
this is more text<tab><return>
text<tab><return>
```

(Using an actual `Tab` and `Return` where indicated.)  Notice what the Tab character does on each of those lines.

To address this, you might add some logic to dynamically add more Tab characters depending on the string length, you might build formatted strings with spaces in between them based on the lengths of values, or you might output to something other than the console with more formatting capabilities (a GUI, a web application, etc.).

Comment: *dynamically add more Tab characters* but surely that gives trouble when tab sizes vary..