# vb.net how to split text file

Tags: vb.net

I have a file with the comma-separated lines as below:

```
PS23456789,08/2023,2011,LAM CHIUE MONG JP
sdad,08/2023,2011,LAM CHIUE MONG JP
xvczxcssf,08/2023,2011,LAM CHIUE MONG JP
42432,08/2023,2011,LAM CHIUE MONG JP
fdsafs,08/2023,2011,LAM CHIUE MONG JP
```

I want to convert this data to fixed-length values and no commas, like this:

```
PS23456789   08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
sdad         08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
xvczxcssf    08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
42432        08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
fdsafs       08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
```

Unfortunately, I can only get the first row to look right. The others do not work. Here is what it looks like:

```
PS23456789   08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
sdad08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
xvczxcssf08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
4243208/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
fdsafs08/2023   2011   LAM CHIUE MONG JP
```

This is my code:

```
Dim splitFile = File.ReadAllText(Result).Split(",")
For count = 0 To splitFile.Length - 1
    While (splitFile(count).Length < 20)
        splitFile(count) = splitFile(count) + " "
    End While
    totalFile += splitFile(count)
Next
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:test.txt", totalFile, False)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. We can't copy text from a picture. Post the text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and that applies double to such a failed attempt at doing so. You can't apply **strong text** formatting to a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do as you want:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Removes delimiters from a file and makes all but the last column a fixed width.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="inputFilePath">
''' The path of the input file.
''' </param>
''' <param name="outputFilePath">
''' The path of the output file. Can be the same as the input file.
''' </param>
''' <param name="delimiter">
''' The field delimiter in the input file.
''' </param>
''' <param name="fieldWidth">
''' The width of the columns in the output file.
''' </param>
Private Sub MakeDelimitedFileFixedWidth(inputFilePath As String,
                                        outputFilePath As String,
                                        delimiter As String,
                                        fieldWidth As Integer)
    'The lines to write to the output file.
    Dim outputLines As New List(Of String)

    For Each line In File.ReadLines(inputFilePath)
        'Split the existing line on the delimiter.
        Dim fields = line.Split({delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        'Pad all but the last column to the specified width.
        For i = 0 To fields.Length - 2
            fields(i) = fields(i).PadRight(fieldWidth)
        Next

        outputLines.Add(String.Concat(fields))
    Next

    'Write out the processed data.
    File.WriteAllLines(outputFilePath, outputLines)
End Sub
```

That will not pad the last column. If you want that then change `fields.Length - 2` to `fields.Length - 1` or `fields.GetUpperBound(0)`.

In your case, you would call it like so:

```vb
MakeDelimitedFileFixedWidth(Result, "C:test.txt", ",", 20)
```

While I haven't examined your existing code in detail, the issue is probably that you were reading the existing data as a single block, then splitting that on the delimiters. That would mean that you would have the last field from one line and the first field from the next line together as one value. That would play havoc with your field length calculations. The code I have provided reads the existing data line by line, so that issue doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's because you are reading all the lines as a whole. The end of each line should be a `\n` symbol, thus the last string of the first line cannot be separated with the first string of the second line. The concatenated string is longer than the length you have defined (i.e. 20), therefore no space is added. You should read the file line by line and process each line separately.

BTW, to add trailing spaces to get fixed length strings, you may want to try String.Format which performs much better.
[Check ref here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644017/net-format-a-string-with-fixed-spaces) Example:
`String.Format({0:-20}, splitFile(count))`